# SQL - Update last occurrence with select in clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-update

In Oracle, I would like do an update on a table for the last occurrence based on select in list, something like :

```
UPDATE table t1
set t1.fieldA = 0
where t1.id in ( 
   select t2.id, max(t2.TIMESTAMP) 
   from table t2 
   where t2.id in (1111,2222,33333) 
   group by t2.id
   );
```

This query does not works, I received an error "too many values".
Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Do not use the sql-server tag for questions about oracle. Highlight code (your sql) and press the brackets button above the text editor {} to format your sql into courier font

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe oracle supports multiple columns IN, so you could try:

```
UPDATE table t1 
set t1.fieldA = 0 
where 
  (t1.id,t1.timestamp) in ( select t2.id, max(t2.TIMESTAMP) from table t2 where t2.id in (1111,2222,33333) group by t2.id );
```

Essentially if you're providing a subquery to the right side of the IN that has a result set with two columns, then you have to provide the names of both the columns in brackets on the left side of the IN

Incidentally, I've never liked updating based on a max value if the requirement is that only one row be updated, as two rows with the same max value will both be updated. This kind of query is better:

```
Update table
Set fieldA=0
Where rowid in(
  select rowid from (
    select rowid, row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc
  ) as rown from table
) where rown=1)
```

If, however, your primary key on the table includes the time stamp as part of the compound, then there is no concern of here being two rows with the same ID/timestamp.. it's just rarely the case!

Comment: I tried your proposal, but I receive an error : SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: My sql works just fine, see this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c124/4 - if you're getting an error it's because you've written something incorrect in your sql when translating the advice youve received here, back to whatever real query you're writing. The error message implies you've forgotten to put a column into the group by list in the inner query. Post up the exact sql that is giving the error and I'll tell you what's wrong with it, but it definitely isn't related to he advice "put all the columns on the right of the IN, into the left side of the IN"

Comment: indeed, I made a typo error. After correction, your proposal works.
Thanks for your quick respones

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect has 2(too many) fields so it cant't be compared with the id.
compare the timestamp with the max timestamp.

```
UPDATE table t1 set t1.fieldA = 0 
where t1.TIMESTAMP = (select max(t2.TIMESTAMP) from table t2 where t2.id = t1.id  )
and id in  (1111,2222,33333)
```

Comment: This query does not answer the question. It causes only one row in the entire table, with the latest time stamp, to be updated, not the latest row per ID. oP is looki for a query that updates multiple rows at a time

Comment: @Caius Jard I think you got that wrong, it  compoutes the max timestamp per id and deletes the records with that timestamp

Comment: Apologies, I think I got that wrong too.. I cannot remove my downvote unless the answer is edited.. but I'll happily remove it if you want to make some inconsequential edit! Sorry

Comment: And i meant update instead of delete, Apologies accepted